# lpr super slow to print

Tags: printing

I am printing some man pages using the command:

man -t (any command) | lpr

It takes a few minutes for the print to come out of the printer, it is a local printer, is there any fine tuning I should do to the lpr command?

Comment: version of ubuntu? type of printer? how printer was installed? Please [edit] your question accordingly to provide information which might be helpful in helping you.

Comment: Network or USB printer?